# Angular js - make uib-datepicker more flexible / forgiving

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

We have a number of date fields on a page using angular js - sample:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control has-error" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="processDTFrom.value" ng-change="processDateSelected('date')" is-open="popupProcessFrom.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" ng-disabled="selectedDateOptionPDF.name !== 'dateRange'" />
```

With format defined as

```
$scope.format = 'MM/dd/yyyy'; //date format for the date picker
```

Currently it only recognizes input as a date if it matches the format exactly - 01/01/2018 is recognized, but 1/1/2018 or 01/01/18 are not.

That just enough of an inconvenience that people are complaining, so I'm trying to see if there's a way to make the function (or the form) a bit smarter so it can recognize more formats.

Later steps take the date and display it in mm/dd/yyyy format, so it'll be standardized later down the line, I'm just keen to make the input more forgiving.

I'd accept adding parameters or whatever to this function, or a better/different one to use, albeit I'd prefer something I don't have to install.  Upgrading to a newer version of angular's not an option at the moment

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As is traditional - the act of asking the question makes the answer magically appear in the following searches.

```
$scope.format = 'M!/d!/y';
```

M! - Parses a numeric month, but allowing an optional leading zero

d! - Parses a numeric day, but allowing an optional leading zero

y - Parses a year with 1, 2, 3, or 4 digits.

The third one technically "allows" you to accidentally ask for the year 2, or 201, but I can but hope people will notice they got no results and look at their entry.

I found a complete (I assume) set of formats on the [github page for Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).